# vb6 check if multiple timers

Tags: vb6, timer

In my application I got few timers, timer1 too timer5. timer1 activates timer2 and so on setting the previous timer to false.

so I want to make another timer that follow these, like "timer6"

```
if timer1.enabled = true then 'then it should check if the timer2 now is enabled
if timer2.enabled = true then 'and so on to it reaches timer5..
```

Need any example to achieve this because I am at a stop point and basically just need this part to work.

my idea was just to do this in the timer6

```
if timer1.enabled = true then
  if timer2.enabled = true then
    if etc etc

    else 

      timer6.enabled = true
      timer6.enabled = false

    end if
  end if
end if
```

end sub

any ideas how to accomplish this?

So.. I am looking for a way to check all the timers are enabled in one condition and disable the last one.

Comment: This is poorly worded, please don't explain it half code and half logic, instead explain the logic fully and then post the code you have tried to write yourself so far.

Comment: Have you considered using control arrays?  You will then have all the timers having the same name but use the Index property to separate them.  Then you can iterate through the collection by index.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can check al the timers at once but what you can do is to keep array of all the timers corresponding Boolean field.

```
 array = collection[timerState{timer1,true},timerState{timer2,false}]
```

Then on each timer enabled/disabled event you keep this state array updated.

and lastly wherever you want you will have the state for all the timers.

Comment: why you want to close? its valid question

Comment: i just thought people closed it when they got a pointer towards what they were looking for and i really think the array might be the solution i want :)

but i guess others might have this problem aswell just in another way so yeah i could leave open for them :o

Comment: @Den Sorte Slyngel - don't close the question. If you found the answer you were looking for, accept the answer by selecting the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the following test project

click the form to start the first timer, click the button to check which timer is active

```
'1 form with
'    1 timer : name=Timer1    Index=0
'    1 command button : name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Timer1(0).Enabled = False
  Timer1(0).Interval = 1000
  For intIndex = 1 To 5
    Load Timer1(intIndex)
    Timer1(intIndex).Interval = intIndex * 1000
  Next intIndex
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Click()
  Timer1(0).Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer(Index As Integer)
  Print CStr(Now)
  Timer1(Index).Enabled = False
  If Index < Timer1.Count - 1 Then
    Timer1(Index + 1).Enabled = True
  Else
    Print "done"
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  For intIndex = 0 To Timer1.Count - 1
    If Timer1(intIndex).Enabled Then
      Caption = "active timer : " & CStr(intIndex)
      Exit For
    End If
  Next intIndex
End Sub
```